# CSS - Chrome Mobile - Page move up when keyboard appears

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, frontend

I implemented a web page with ReactJS, I have a form with some fields, in Chrome for computers it works ok, but when I go in the form using a mobile like a Tablet or Smartphone, when the keyboard appears all the page move to up and the menu of my page is hiden by the navigation bar of the Chrome navigator.

Here is the flow:
[image]

I have the next meta in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
```

The problem only happens in chrome for mobile devices.

Comment: make you menu position fixed if you want it to remain at the top of the screen always, but you need to create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem (and not just show pictures of it) otherwise this question is off topic for SO

Comment: Can you add your html/css for the menu ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would say that you have a **margin-top** or a a **padding-top** set with relative units like **vh**.
I think of this because when the keyboard appears, the viewport will be reduced and these units will ajust themselves, making these kind of situations.

Comment: You were right. Actually, the problem was in the component bar, there was a calc(100vh - 60px) so I changed this to be a static value, now it is working ok. Thank you so much.